# Is safe use KeyFactory.keyToString as id for identifying records in the client layout

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

KeyFactory.keyToString string representation **is look already encrypted**

Example:

```
...
    Key  key  = KeyFactory.stringToKey("ag1zYW50b21lcmNhZG9zcgoLEgRUcmVlGAEM");

        try {
           Entity entity = datastoreService.get(key);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
           map.addAttribute("EntityNotFoundException",       e.getMessage());
           map.addAttribute("status",                        false);
        }
...

private ModelMap organizeData(Entity entity){

   Map     properties   =              entity.getProperties();
   Key     key          =              entity.getKey();
   String  key_string   =              KeyFactory.keyToString(key);

   ModelMap data = new ModelMap();

   data.addAttribute("properties",     properties);
   data.addAttribute("keyString",      key_string);

   return data;
}


public ArrayList<ModelMap> getTree() {
   ArrayList<ModelMap> treeLists = new ArrayList<ModelMap>();

   Query query = new Query("Tree");

   query.addSort("left", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);

   for(Entity entity:datastoreService.prepare(query).asIterable()){

      // Todo -> Organize Data as ModelMap Obj
      ModelMap model = organizeData(entity);

      treeLists.add(model);

   }

   return treeLists;
}
```

I asking because in

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

The string representation of a key is "web-safe": it does not contain characters considered special in HTML or in URLs.

Note: The KeyFactory.keyToString method is different from Key.toString, which returns a human-readable string suitable for use in debugging and logging. If you need a string value that can be converted to a usable key, use KeyFactory.keyToString.

**Note also that a key's string representation is not encrypted**: a user can decode the key string to extract its components, including the kinds and identifiers of the entity and its ancestors. If it is important to conceal this information from the user, you must encrypt the key string yourself before sending it to the user.

**they are referring to Key.toString?**

because i send to client layout this JSON

```
[
   {
      "properties":{
         "parent":null,
         "left":1,
         "right":2,
         "name":"laptops"
      },
      "keyString":"ag1zYW50b21lcmNhZG9zcgoLEgRUcmVlGAEM"
   },
   {
      "properties":{
         "parent":null,
         "left":3,
         "right":4,
         "name":"Pc"
      },
      "keyString":"ag1zYW50b21lcmNhZG9zcgoLEgRUcmVlGAIM"
   }
...
```

**is safe using keyString?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They refer to `KeyFactory.keyToString` which is not encrypted, just encoded with Base64 or similar base.
Their concern is that if you send your key to the user, it might pose a problem, since it can be used to create requests to retrieve data from the datastorage.

Comment: If you want to encrypt the Key. I'd suggest to create a wrapper for the datastore service and the KeyProvider, overriding the  with some simple encryption algorithms. If the encryption/decryption stay only at server side, it avoid the problem of sending the plain key to the client. If you want, I can code an example later and update this answer.

Comment: I like and get the idea, i have already one wrapper or interfaz for datastore service, i will write encrypt process for Key, with this tutorial:  http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/ ,thank you very much André !!!

Comment: Hmm, you have to encrypt, don't use MD5 or SHA, because you can't turn the key back to it's plain form. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm, Blowfish, Triple DES are good examples. It works because only the server would know the secret of the Symmetric algorithm.